# Get last day of previous month in SQL

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to get a function for the last day of the previous month without the time show, that is, 2019-09-30 for last month.

This is the code I have tried

```
SELECT DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE()),0))
```

expected results now 2019-09-30
actual results

Answer (score 5):

try using the EOMONTH function with an offset:

```
SELECT EOMONTH('2019-10-29', -1)
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use `EOMONTH()` function, which return type is `date`, while the return type for `DATEADD()` is dynamic and depends on the argument supplied for date. In your case the result from `DATEADD(s,-1, DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE()), 0))` is `datetime` data type, because `0` is [implicitly converted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-conversion-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15#implicit-and-explicit-conversion) to `datetime` value `01/01/1900 00:00:00` (implicit conversion between `int` and `date` is not allowed).

```
SELECT EOMONTH(DATEADD(month, -1, GETDATE()))
-- or
SELECT EOMONTH(GETDATE(), -1)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you take the day of today's date, and subtract it from today's date, it will give you the last day of the previous month.

```
SELECT DATEADD(DY, -DAY(getdate()), cast(getdate() as date))
```

note the cast to 'DATE' type to give date only

Answer (score 1):

You should try this way as I showed in the example below.

**Solution 1:**

> Last Day of Previous Month

```
SELECT DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE()),0))
LastDay_PreviousMonth
```

**Solution 2:**

> Last Day of Current Month

```
SELECT DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE())+1,0))
LastDay_CurrentMonth
```

**Solution 3:**

> Last Day of Next Month

```
SELECT DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE())+2,0))
LastDay_NextMonth
```